# move_pallet: What is correct way to verify old pallet storage is deleted

Tags: storage, runtime-upgrade, migration

In trying to use a migration implementation for substrate which can be used to rename `BagsList` to `VoterList`, using `move_pallet` a post migration check is failing when testing the migration with `try-runtime`.

The failing [post upgrade check](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/polkadot-v0.9.30/frame/staking/src/migrations.rs#L156) is ensuring that storage at the old prefix is removed with

```rust
sp_io::storage::next_key(&old_pallet_prefix).is_none()
```

Another similar migration for the collectives pallet, does a check [differently](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/9115/files#diff-1dee027b2fa4c245bc171233ac07ec714f3fdc9a83a0f428adf67a2966049717R125)

```rust
    // Assert that nothing remains at the old prefix.
    let old_pallet_prefix = twox_128(old_pallet_name.as_bytes());
    let old_pallet_prefix_iter = frame_support::storage::KeyPrefixIterator::new(
        old_pallet_prefix.to_vec(),
        old_pallet_prefix.to_vec(),
        |_| Ok(()),
    );
    assert_eq!(old_pallet_prefix_iter.count(), 0);
```

In the documentation for `move_pallet` there is [comment](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a3ed0119c45cdd0d571ad34e5b3ee7518c8cef8d/frame/support/src/storage/migration.rs#L351):

"NOTE: The value at the key `twox_128(old_pallet_name)` is not moved."

Interestingly the polkadot chain performed a migration in runtime upgrade to spec_version [9230](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.23/runtime/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L1529) renaming `BagsList` to `VoterList` with `move_pallet` but no post upgrade try-runtime checks for old prefix removal were added.

Questions:

1. What would cause the check `sp_io::storage::next_key(&old_pallet_prefix).is_none()` to fail? Is it the noted behavior of move_pallet suggesting that the author did not perform the correct check and this was never tested in production?
2. Is the approach of constructing a `KeyPrefixIterator` for the old prefix and testing `iterator.count() == 0` correct?